# Ruby RSpec unit test gives undefined method error

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have created a unit test using RSpec.

The app.rb has:

```
module AppModule
  class App
    def get_item
      str = self.get_string
      puts "in get_item - #{str}"
    end

    def get_string
      puts "hello, world"
    end
  end
end
```

The app_test.rb has:

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'env'

describe App do
  before :each do
    @var = App.new
  end

  describe "firsttest" do
    it "should print string" do
      @var.get_item
    end
  end
end
```

What I find is that get_item is called correctly.  But when it gets to get_string, I get an error:

undefined method get_string for #App:0x2eaqc4600

Thanks.

Comment: (Unrelated, but you know `str = get_string`, even if it worked, will set `str` to `nil`, right?)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a namespace issue. I don't know about your environment, but are you sure that @var is an instance of AppModule::App and not just ::App ?